# Print string objects from object array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, object, out-of-memory

I am creating an array of objects to assign each object to another array of objects. The code below includes an attempt to print the objects from the array. My class has attributes for a person's name, a count of how many friends they may have, and a capacity variable for extending the size of the array if needed. The class also initializes a pointer to a pointer, intended to be used for an array of objects.

I want to print the names of the objects in the array, and also the objects pointed to by each element of the first array. However, the printFriends() method will not accept my usage of the dot operator for the string variable used. Please see the printFriends() method below.

Compiler - G++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) 5.4.0. Vim text editor. Error report found below.

Person.h

```
class Person {
private:
  Person **friends = NULL;
  int friend_count = 0; 
  int friend_capacity = 0;
  std::string name;

public: 
  Person(std::string n) {
    friends = new Person*[100];
    friend_capacity = 100;
    for ( int i = 0; i < friend_capacity; i++ )
      friends[i] = NULL;
    name = n;
  }



void growFriends() {
  Person **tmp = friends; //Keep up with the old list
  int newSize = friend_capacity * 2; //We will double the size of the list

  friends = new Person*[newSize]; //Make a new list twice the size of original

  for (int i = 0; i < friend_capacity; i++) {
    //Copy the old list of friends to the new list.
    friends[i] = tmp[i];
  }

  delete[] tmp;  //delete the old list of friends
  friend_capacity = newSize; //update the friend count
}

void printFriends() {
  for ( int i = 0; i < friend_count; i++ )
    std::cout << friends[i].name << std::endl;
}



/*
void addFriend(const Person &obj) {
  Person **tmp = friends;
//    Person f = new std::string(obj);   

  for (int i = 0; i < friend_capacity; i++)
    friends[friend_count + 1] + obj; 

  friend_count = friend_count + 1; 
}

*/

};
```

Person-test.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include"Person.h"
int main() {

Person p1("Shawn");
p1.printFriends(); 

}
```

g++ --std=c++11 person-test.cpp -o p

In file included from Person-test.cpp:2:0:
person.h: In member function ‘void Person::printFriends()’:
person.h:46:31: error: request for member ‘name’ in ‘*(((Person*)this)->Person::friends + ((sizetype)(((long unsigned int)i) * 8ul)))’, which is of pointer type ‘Person*’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)
       std::cout << friends[i].name << std::endl;

The error message is blatantly clear with this, and I understand a couple ways to remove the error. One being to use the arrow notation since I am indeed using a pointer. However, this results in a segmentation fault.

I want to print the objects in the array by iterating across the array's elements. How can I accomplish this simply? Using the dot notation is not functional in my program as shown above with the error message, though I would like to access the string to print each name in the object array, and additionally each object array's elements being pointed to from the first object array.

Answer (score 0):

`friends` is an array of pointers; so `friends[i]` is a pointer; you need to "dereference" that to get to a member field:

`std::cout << friends[i].name << std::endl;` reads like:

```
Person* friendI = friends[i];
std::cout << friendI.name << std::endl;
```

but you want to go "through" the `friendI` pointer; so it needs to be:

```
std::cout << friendI->name << std::endl;
```

or (without the temporary variable):

```
std::cout << friends[i]->name << std::endl;
```

Comment: Note; I don't think this is the _only_ issue, but since you're learning the syntax it should help get you started.

Comment: This returns a segmentation fault. I am trying to debug with gdb. But it seems I need a core dump file, and I'm not entirely sure at this point how to generate one.

Comment: The segmentation fault means that the pointer doesn't go to memory that you've allocated. You allocate the array, but not the items in it. C++ is a stickler for things like that. Each entry you use needs to first be initialised with a `new Person( ... )`